# How to get exclusive SMS received permission for my app

Tags: android, permissions, sms

I'm trying to get my app a permission to be the only app which can intercept an SMS from a specific phone number. Is this possible?

Comment: Reformatted title and changed spelling in body

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, no one is going to write this for you but we can help. You have to create a home screen replacement and then have the user select to always use your home screen. From there you can restrict which applications the user can launch by not allowing them the option to actually launch any of them. Kytephone basically has this implemented.

On a stock device applications cannot block/shutdown another application. So it would not be possible w/o creating a new homescreen.

If you just meant which permission to put in the manifest to allow SMS communication than you should look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html